# Generics with Dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics

I want to return a dictionary but there are 2 types of keys that I can have so I want to include T in my return value. Any Ideas?

```
like so

public static Dictionary<string, T> Read<T>(string dicValueType, string path)
{ 

    if(dicValueType.Equals("User"))
    {
       Dictionary<string, User> usersDictionary = 
                   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, User>> 
                                                     (File.ReadAllText(path));
       return usersDictionary;
    }
    Dictionary<string, Column> boardDictionary = 
                     JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Column>> 
                                                (File.ReadAllText(path));
    return boardDictionary;
}
```

I'm getting an error in this line "return usersDictionary;"

Comment: Don't make a method generic when there are only two valid values, and any other values just make it break. If you want to do one of two things, then have two methods, and call the appropriate one for each situation.

Comment: in addition to what @Servy said, you could consider a class to hold either of the value and return what is apropriate via getter method.

Comment: But there is no way to do it as I wish? today it's 2 options, tomorrow it can be 500

Comment: @somene [dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SCjxVH) have a look at this, maybe that would be something that'll help your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't all you want to deserialize a JSON object to generic. This will do it without all the `if-else` checks:

```
public static Dictionary<string, T> Read<T>(string path) 
    => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, T>>(File.ReadAllText(path));
```

Comment: dictionary.GetType() is Dictionary<string,User>        how can i compare between them?    [dictionary looks like this: dictionary<string,T>]

Comment: @somene I'm not sure what you mean, it would be best to open a new question with a MCVE example.

Comment: Ah, I think you're looking for `if (dict.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<string, User>))`